# When using SUMIF function, is there a way to accept timestamp values (e.g. 2/12/2019 19:56:16) as the range to test against the criteria?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm working with two columns,

- column A: a list of timestamps
- column B: a list of numbers

I'm trying to use the `sumif(range, criteria, [sum range])` function to check if the month in column A is January, and so on for all months.

The issue is that I need a way to either convert the range for the `sumif` to month names, or use criteria other than a string (because a timestamp isn't going to ever be `"=January"`.

My thought was that I could do either

```
=sumif(TEXT(TO_DATE(A2:A),"mmmm"), "=January", B2:B)
```

or

```
=sumif(A2:A, TEXT(TO_DATE(A2:A),"mmmm")="January", B2:B)
```

*these are more or less pseudo-code, I'm trying to convey my thought process*

I understand I could create a new column that converts the timestamps into months, but is there anyway I can preform this `sumif`, without having to make a new column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SUMIFS, with dates you set the extents, this works in excel and google sheets:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">=" & DATE(2019,1,1),A:A,"<" & DATE(2019,2,1))
```

With Google Sheets you can also use filter:

```
=SUM(FILTER(B:B,MONTH(A:A)=1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### `"=2"` = February, `"=3"` = March, etc.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(MONTH(A2:A), "=2", B2:B))
```

[image]

if you want to select it from a drop-down menu use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(MONTH(A2:A), "="&MONTH(F2&1), B2:B))
```

[image]